# Unit test security of ASP.NET MVC controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

Are there any recommended ways to unit test the security of one's MVC controller methods for security (in ASP.NET MVC 5)? e.g. I have administrator users and normal users, and I want to have a unit test to ensure that only administrators can access certain pages. e.g.:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initial page for creating a new <see cref="Widget"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="ActionResult"/> used to indicate the view to be
    /// rendered. Guaranteed not to be null or empty.
    /// </returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return this.View(new CreateWidgetModel());
    }
```

... and the unit test should be something like:

```
using (var userStore = new MyUserStore())
{
    using (var userManager = new MyUserManager(userStore))
    {
        if (await userManager.HasAdministratorUserAsync())
        {
            await userStore.DeleteAsync(await userManager.FindByNameAsync(MyUserManager.AdministratorUserName));
        }

        ApplicationUser adminUser = await userManager.CreateAdministratorUserAsync();

        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(adminUser, "Forms");

        this.MockHttpContext.SetupGet(x => x.User).Returns(new GenericPrincipal(claimsIdentity, adminUser.Roles.ToArray()));

        List<MethodInfo> methodInfos = this.Sut.GetType().GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Create" && typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(m.ReturnType)).ToList();

        Assert.AreEqual(2, methodInfos.Count, "Unexpected number of create methods");

        foreach (var method in methodInfos)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(method.IsDefined(typeof(ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute)), "No ClaimsAuthorize attribute was placed on the method");

            ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute<ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute>();

            Assert.AreEqual(1, attribute.Claims.Length, "Unexpected number of claims");

            AuthorizationContext authorizationContext = new AuthorizationContext(this.Sut.ControllerContext, new ReflectedActionDescriptor(method, "Create", new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(this.Sut.GetType())));

            attribute.OnAuthorization(authorizationContext);

            Assert.IsNotNull(authorizationContext.Result, "The authorization context result must not be null");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into right now is that `attribute.OnAuthorization` fails with a null reference exception like the following:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at  System.Web.Mvc.OutputCacheAttribute.GetChildActionFilterFinishCallback(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    at System.Web.Mvc.OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    at System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
```

*EDIT*: After seeing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314340/nullreferenceexception-thrown-when-testing-custom-authorizationattribute), I've now got a different null reference exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    at MyProject.Support.Security.ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) in ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute.cs: line 106
```

*EDIT*: After seeing the source code for `OnAuthorization` [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1acb241299a8#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs), adding this to my test solved my problem:

```
        this.MockHttpResponse.Setup(x => x.Cache).Returns(new Mock<HttpCachePolicyBase>().Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection:

```
using System.Reflection;
var isAdmin = typeof(Controller).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Create").GetCustomAttribute<Authorize>(false).Roles == "ADMIN";
```

The basic idea is to get the attribute from the method and check for Roles.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've already got something based on that, but I'm running into a problem with a null reference exception.

Comment: I think you are testing code that is part of the ASP.NET framework. The point is to test _your_ code.

Comment: Please look again - it's not my code that I'm testing, but my configuration specified by my code via the claims specified in the ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute

Answer (score 0):

The easist way is to use the [Xania.AspNet.Simulator 1.2.3-beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xania.AspNet.Simulator/1.2.3-beta) (or higher) then you can write tests like following:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using Xania.AspNet.Simulator;

    [TestCase("ADMIN", true)]
    [TestCase("CUSTOMER", false)]
    public void AdminRoleAuthorizationTest(string roleName, bool isAuthorized)
    {
        // arrange
        var action = new AdminController().Action(c => c.Index()).Authenticate("user1", new[] {roleName});
        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual(isAuthorized, action.Authorize() == null);
    }
```

For more examples refer to the Tests project at github

- https://github.com/ibrahimbensalah/Xania.AspNet.Simulator